# Flash with SwiftUI/AV Foundation Error code -16800

Tags: swiftui, avfoundation

I am trying to use flash when taking an image using AV Foundation in Swift UI. However, when I try to take a picture, I get the following error code.

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x28004e790 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16800 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16800), AVErrorRecordingFailureDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Below is the code that I am using for my camera that is generating this issue. I have gone through and commented some areas that I thought might be the source of the issue as I was trying to figure this out, but I may be wrong.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct Camera: View {
    var body: some View {
        CameraView()
    }
}

struct Camera_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

// Test code: Ignore
struct globalVariable {
    public var isBack = false
}
class GlobalModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var isBack = false
    func get() -> Bool{
        return isBack
    }
    func setTrue() {
        isBack = true
    }
    func setFalse() {
        isBack = false
    }
}
// 

struct CameraView: View { // Creates the camera preview elements
    @StateObject var camera = CameraModel()
    @State var img : UIImage? = nil
    @State var navigated = false
    @ObservedObject var nextScreen = GlobalModel()
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            CameraPreview(camera: camera)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all)
            
            VStack{
                
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    if camera.isTaken {
                        Button(action: {
                            camera.reTake()
                            self.nextScreen.setFalse()
                            print(nextScreen.get())
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Retake").foregroundColor(.black)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                                .background(Color.white)
                                .clipShape(Capsule())
                        }).padding(.trailing)
                        Spacer()
                        ZStack{
                            NavigationLink("", destination: Classify(originalImage: img, label: "", confidence: 0.0), isActive: $navigated)
                            Button(action:
                                {if !camera.isLoaded{
                                    img = camera.savePic()
                                    if img != nil{
                                        print("is not nil")
                                    }
                                    self.navigated.toggle()
                                    self.nextScreen.setTrue()
                                    print(nextScreen.get())
                                   
                                }
                                
                                }, label: {
                                Text("Continue").foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                                    .background(Color.white)
                                    .clipShape(Capsule())
                                }).padding(.leading).opacity(nextScreen.get() ? 0.01 : 1)
                            }
                    }
                    else{
                        Button(action: camera.takePic, label: {
                            ZStack{
                                Image(systemName: "camera.circle")
                                    .frame(width: 70, height: 75).font(.system(size: 60))
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }.frame(height: 75)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation") // Forcing the rotation to portrait
            AppDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait // And making sure it stays that way
            //UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
            camera.Check()
            
        })
        .onDisappear(){
            AppDelegate.orientationLock = .all
            UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = false
        }
    }
}



class CameraModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    @Published var isTaken = false
    
    @Published var session = AVCaptureSession()
    
    @Published var alert = false
    
    @Published var output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    @Published var preview : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    
    @Published var isLoaded = false
    
    @Published var picData = Data(count: 0)
    
     var flashMode: AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode = .on // set the camera to on
    
    var device : AVCaptureDevice? // for camera device
    
    
    private func getSettings(camera: AVCaptureDevice, flashMode: AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode) -> AVCapturePhotoSettings {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()  // get the default settings 
 and change them to enable flash

        if camera.hasFlash {
            settings.flashMode = self.flashMode
        }
        

        return settings
    }
    
    
    func Check() {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video){
        case .authorized:
            setUp()
            return
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { (status) in
                if status{
                    self.setUp()
                }
            }
        case .denied:
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
            
        default:
            return
        }
    }


    
    func setUp(){
        
        do{
            
            self.session.beginConfiguration()
            
            self.device = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
            

    
            
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.device!)
            
            
            if self.session.canAddInput(input){
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
            
            if self.session.canAddOutput(self.output){
                self.session.addOutput(self.output)
            }
            
            
            
            self.session.commitConfiguration()
            
            
        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func takePic(){
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let currentSettings = self.getSettings(camera: self.device!, flashMode: self.flashMode) 
            self.output.capturePhoto(with: currentSettings, delegate: self) // Capture photo with flash settings; doesn't work
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false){
                    
                    (timer) in self.session.stopRunning()
                    //isBack.setTrue()
                }
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            withAnimation{
                self.isTaken.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func reTake() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.session.startRunning()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation{
                    self.isTaken.toggle()
                    self.isLoaded = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) // not sure if there is something wrong here that is messing up the program but need this function to work ultimately{
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
        }
        
        print("photoOuput function")
       
        print(photo)
        
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else{return }
    
        
        self.picData = imageData
        
    }
    
    func savePic () -> UIImage{
        let image = UIImage(data: self.picData)!
        self.isLoaded = true
        return image
        
    }

}


struct CameraPreview: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var camera : CameraModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        
        
        camera.preview = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: camera.session)
        camera.preview.frame = view.frame
        
        
        camera.preview.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(camera.preview)
        
        camera.session.startRunning()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
    
}
```

I noticed that if I set the following line from above

```
var flashMode: AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode = .on
```

to

```
var flashMode: AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode = .off
```

the app doesn't produce the above error (but flash stays off). I am asking this because I need to save the output of the camera (with flash) as an image, however, with flash enabled, the picData is nil which leads to an unwrapping error (see the savePic() and photoOutput() functions for reference). Ultimately, I need the savePic() function to work

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: Observation; you should not have `@State var flashMode...` in your `CameraModel`, `@State` is for `Views` only.

Comment: appreciate the feedback; updated the post without the @State, but the error still remains in the app

Comment: it may not be related, but I used to have this in my code: `if camera.hasFlash && camera.isFlashAvailable { settings.flashMode = .on }`

Comment: Tried that change, and some other ones, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you found a way to fix this, but on my side I had fixed it by moving the code :

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { (timer) in
    self.cameraManager.session.stopRunning()
    }
}
```

instead of having it right after the call to capture photo, I moved it inside my PhotoCameraViewModel where I have :

```swift
cameraManager.$picture
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .compactMap { image in
                if image != nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false) { (timer) in
                            self.cameraManager.session.stopRunning()
                        }
                    }
                }
                return image
            }
            .assign(to: &$selectedFrame)
```

What I understood is that the session was being stop before the picture using flash was taken